# Fast dot-matrix printing with PHP

Tags: php, printing

My client has old foxpro based application in Windows and wanted to make it web based with PHP/MySQL. The only problem is the printing of their various reports/receipts. That foxpro based application facilitating fast printing on dot-matrix printers using some mode etc. (sorry I'm not sure here).

So if there's a webform created by php and we want to print, it goes to printer and starts printing each line (repeating on each line multiple times to make it bold and slow). This is default behavior for other apps as well, whether its word/excel etc. but few old apps like DOS based text file when you print, it will again print very fast (printing a line only once, therefore though making it rough but fast).

Any insight how to achieve this using PHP? any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Is PHP running on the machine the printer is connected to?

Answer (score 2):

Use Firefox ,and JSPrintSetup add-on at this  [Link](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/js-print-setup/) for a silent printing.

Sample code which demonstrate using of JSPrintSetup to setup print margins and call unattended print method (without print dialog).

```
// set portrait orientation
jsPrintSetup.setOption('orientation', jsPrintSetup.kPortraitOrientation);
// set top margins in millimeters
jsPrintSetup.setOption('marginTop', 0);
jsPrintSetup.setOption('marginBottom', 0);
jsPrintSetup.setOption('marginLeft', 0);
jsPrintSetup.setOption(' marginRight', 0);
// set empty page header
jsPrintSetup.setOption('headerStrLeft', '');
jsPrintSetup.setOption('headerStrCenter', '');
jsPrintSetup.setOption('headerStrRight', '');
// set empty page footer
jsPrintSetup.setOption('footerStrLeft', '');
jsPrintSetup.setOption('footerStrCenter', '');
jsPrintSetup.setOption('footerStrRight', '');
// Suppress print dialog
jsPrintSetup.setSilentPrint(true);
// Do Print
jsPrintSetup.print();
// Restore print dialog
jsPrintSetup.setSilentPrint(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

To elaborate on what Pekka is digging at. If you are running PHP as a local language, and not over the web, you can access the local system directly and at a low enough level to print the way you want WITH the programs that print those DOS text files.

But I suspect you mean over the web, in which case the answer is a solid no.

Comment: Well, I dont think those programs can facilitate printing of those complex reports etc. But I can work on idea (though not looks like best) where reporting only done by foxpro and all other interface/interaction will be provided by PHP/web.

Answer (score 0):

EPSON ESC/P control codes
Selecting an EPSON ESC/P printer in your software allows you to use advanced fonts and graphics.
General operation:

ESC @, ESC U
Paper feeding:

FF, LF, ESC 0, ESC 1, ESC 2, ESC 3, ESC A, CR
Page format:

ESC (C, ESC C, ESC C 0, ESC Q, ESC l, ESC (c, ESC N, ESC O, ESC (U
Print position motion:

ESC $, ESC \, ESC D, HT, ESC B, VT, ESC J
Font selection:

ESC k, ESC x, ESC y, ESC P, ESC M, ESC g, ESC p, ESC 4, ESC 5, ESC E, ESC F, ESC !
Font enhancement:

ESC W, DC4, SO, DC2, SI, ESC w, ESC G, ESC H, ESC T, ESC S, ESC -
Spacing:

ESC Space
Character handling:

ESC t, ESC (t, ESC R, ESC %, ESC &, ESC :, ESC I, ESC 6,
ESC 7
Bit image:

ESC K, ESC L, ESC Y, ESC Z, ESC *, ESC ^
Bar code:

ESC (B

IBM PPDS emulation control codes
This printer emulates the IBM Proprinter using the commands below. For detailed information, see the IBM PPDS reference manual.
General operation:

NUL, DC3, ESC j, BEL, CAN, DC1, ESC Q, ESC [ K, ESC U
Paper feeding:

FF, LF, ESC 5, ESC A, ESC 0, ESC 1, ESC 2, ESC 3, CR, ESC ]
Page format:

ESC C, ESC C0, ESC X, ESC N, ESC O, ESC 4
Print position motion:

ESC d, ESC R, ESC D, HT, ESC B, VT, ESC J
Font selection:

DC2, ESC P, ESC :, ESC E, ESC F, ESC I, ESC [d, ESC [I
Font enhancement:

DC4, SO, ESC SO, ESC W, ESC [ @, SI, ESC SI, ESC G, ESC H, ESC T,
ESC S, ESC -, ESC _
Spacing:

BS, SP
Character handling:

ESC 6, ESC 7, ESC [ T, ESC ^, ESC ¥
Bit image:

ESC K, ESC L, ESC Y, ESC Z
Bar code:

ESC [f, ESC [p
Download:

ESC =